# Converting a hugging face model into complete .pt file

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

I have downloaded a Hugging Face model, and it comes with various files, including pytorch_model.bin, config.json, and others. My goal is to integrate this model into my project, and I would like to convert it into a single .pt file for ease of use. Can someone guide me through the steps or provide a script to achieve this?

Additional Information:

```
   Hugging Face Model Name: IndicWhisper
```

I've explored using the transformers library, but I'm unsure about the specific steps for this conversion. Any help, guidance, or sample scripts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried renaming the pytorch_model.bin to pytorch_model.pt and use it but failed. The error message comes out as  KeyError: 'dims'

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this part of the documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/serialization#saving-a-model

> *This snippet shows how to use TorchScript to export a BertModel. Here the BertModel is instantiated according to a BertConfig class and then saved to disk under the filename traced_bert.pt*